# Usage of "other" with singular nouns

Tags: grammar, adjectives, pronouns

Reading an English textbook and learning stuff, they mention that that "other" is used only with plural or uncountable nouns.
But what about this?

> There is no **other** way..no **other** option. Car ends up on its side, No
>   **other** car involved!

Especially the last one, how could I say that without the "other" word?

Comment: Perhaps the book meant nouns that can have a plural form.

Comment: But a "car" can be plural..ALso a lot of sites I found says the same. I do not get it.

Comment: `There are no other ways, no other options, no other cars involved` are perfectly fine... Not sure what they mean

Comment: Yes but sentences I posted are with singular and I believe they are correct. According to the textbook, they are not. But the sentence with the car is taken from the newspaper so I hope it is right.

Comment: There is no other way. / There is one other way. / There is some other way. / There is another way. are all fine. There is other wine. / There is other butter. are also fine, using relevant mass nouns. There are other ways. uses a plural noun, and is again fine. *There is other way / *There is other dog. are not grammatical, as they use singular count nouns in **non-negative** and **non-pre-quantified** (contrast 'one other way') structures.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If "There is other wine/butter" is grammatically correct, it's certainly not idiomatic. I'd expect "there is more wine/butter" if someone wanted more of the same variety or "there are other wines/butters" if one wanted a different variety, but I can't come up with a case where "there is other wine/butter" doesn't sound awkward at best.

Answer (score 1):

The term ***Other*** means

> Being the one (as of two or more) remaining or not included.

Therefore, usage of it in your sentence is perfectly correct :)